# use input filter constant pass to all queries graphql, apollo-client, react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-gql

I have the following defined in my apollo server instance

```
input FilterInput {
  menuOneId: Int!
  menuTwoId: Int!
  menuThreeId: Int!
  menuFourId: Int!
  menuFiveId: Int!
  menuSixId: Int!
  dateFrom: String
  dateTo: String
}
```

and when I query inside apollo playground, like so it works like you would expect

```
query getMenuItems($input: FilterInput!) {
  getMenutems(input: $input) {
    menuOne
    menuTwo
    menuThree
    menuFour
    menuFive
    menuSix
  }
}
```

Query Variables are as such

```
{
 "input": {
  "menuOneId": 1,
  "menuTwoId": 3,
  "menuThreeId": 2,
  "menuFourId": 6,
  "menuFiveId": 4,
  "menuSixId": 5,
  "dateFrom": "2020-03-01",
  "dateTo": "2020-03-15"
 }
}
```

So my question is how to I mimic this in my front end react application to use on defined set of Filters per all the queries I have setup since the all use the same set of FilterInput items.

I defined what I thought was correct as follows in my **lib/graphql/queries** file

```
export const filter = gql`
input FilterInput {
   menuOneId: Int!
   menuTwoId: Int!
   menuThreeId: Int!
   menuFourId: Int!
   menuFiveId: Int!
   menuSixId: Int!
   dateFrom: String
   dateTo: String
}
`;
```

and then the saved query

```
export const getMenuItems = gql`
   query ($input: filter){ // have also tried FilterInput!
    getMenuItems(input: $input) {
        menuOne
        menuTwo
        menuThree
        menuFour
        menuFive
        menuSix
    }
}
`;
```

these are the two different results that were generated when attempting to get this working

```
{
    "variables": {
        "menuOneId": 0,
        "menuTwoId": 0,
        "menuThreeId": 0,
        "menuFourId": 0,
        "menuFiveId": 0,
        "menuSixId": 0,
        "dateFrom": "2020-03-01",
        "dateTo": "2020-03-15"
    },
    "query": "query ($input: FilterInput!) {\n  getMenuItems(input: $input) {\n    MenuOne\n    MenuTwo\n    MenuThree\n    MenuFour\n    MenuFive\n    MenuSix\n }\n}\n"
}
- and -
{
    "variables": {
        "menuOneId": 0,
        "menuTwoId": 0,
        "menuThreeId": 0,
        "menuFourId": 0,
        "menuFiveId": 0,
        "menuSixId": 0,
        "dateFrom": "2020-03-01",
        "dateTo": "2020-03-15"
    },
    "query": "query ($input: filter) {\n  getMenuItems(input: $input) {\n    MenuOne\n    MenuTwo\n    MenuThree\n    MenuFour\n    MenuFive\n    MenuSix\n }\n}\n"
}
```

as opposed two when I run it the normal way like

```
{
    "variables": {
        "menuOneId": 0,
        "menuTwoId": 0,
        "menuThreeId": 0,
        "menuFourId": 0,
        "menuFiveId": 0,
        "menuSixId": 0,
        "dateFrom": "2020-01-01",
        "dateTo": "2020-01-30"
    },
    "query": "query ($menuOneId: Int!, $menuTwoId: Int!, $menuThreeId: Int!, $menuFourId: Int!, $menuFiveId: Int!, $menuSix: Int!, $dateFrom: String!, $dateTo: String!) {\n  getMenuItems(\n    input: {menuOneId: $menuOneId, menuTwoId: $menuTwoId, menuThreeId: $menuThreeId, menuFourId: $menuFourId, menuFiveId: $menuFiveId, menuSixId: $menuSixId, dateFrom: $dateFrom, dateTo: $dateTo}\n  ) {\n    MenuOne\n    MenuTwo\n    MenuThree\n    MenuFour\n    MenuFive\n    MenuSix\n  }\n}\n"
}
```

Is it even possible to do it from react using a single defined set of input filters, just can't figure out how to put it all together at this point.

Comment: `"query": "query ($input: FilterInput!) ` ... and variables with missing `"input"`

Comment: was hoping for a bit more of an example, I already knew there was differences was really trying to not have to duplicate everything, guess that's the way I will be using for now. Thanks for the response